# How to raise PR request to approve without merging code changes into parent branch?

Tags: git, github

As per scenario, we need a PR review for branch(`b`), but we donot want to merge the code changes of branch(`b`) to parent branch(`master`).

Because, we want to create another(second) PR in future for same branch(`b`) and then merge code changes of branch(`b`) in parent branch(`master`)

Is this possible from GitHub?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking: the goal of a pull request is to get code merged into some branch. What do you want to happen with the code in your pull request, if not have it merged to `master`?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then I think this question would be much clearer if you add the word "yet" to the end of the first sentence. I think you simply want to use the code review features of a PR without completing the PR, "yet". Later when more changes are added, you could continue reviewing those new changes and then finally complete the PR. (I don't think you need two separate PRs.)

Comment: @larsks For your question: "What do you want to happen with the code in your pull reques"--- I want to have code reviewed only(by adding comments).

Answer (score 1):

[Draft PR](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests#draft-pull-requests) functionality offered by Github, serves exactly this purpose. You can create a Draft PR, get it reviewed, if required, and continue to work on it until it is ready to be merged. Draft PRs won't be allowed to be merged until you convert the Draft PR into a PR.

It's possible to change any Draft PR into a PR and vice versa.

For new PR, select "Create draft Pull Request".

[image: Choose Create draft pull request]

For existing PR, select "Convert to draft".

[image: Convert to Draft]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, it's common to make another branch for the changes of b.
Create another branch by checking out, and then push it.

1. Click `Pull requests`
2. Click `New pull request`
3. Select `b` for the base, and `[newly created branch]` for the compare
4. Create pull request
5. Review

You would easily find out how to do the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have worked on a branch b, committed it, pushed it to the remote repo, created a PR for merging it to the master, and waiting for the approval.

Now, you made changes to the branch in local and then pushed it in the same remote branch forcefully. It is up to you whether you want to have one commit or two commits. If you want to do one commit then you need to use the following command.

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

Pushing the same branch to the remote can be done by using `-f` flag.

```
git push origin branch-b -f
```

Then in your PR, it will show you that you have removed one commit and added one commit as we had before amended it.

This is the case only when you have pushed the branch to the remote and then later you are the one who is making the changes in the same branch. You already have the same branch in the local and made changes to the same branch and later pushed it.

---

There is another scenario when you have pushed the branch to remote and created a PR and this time you are not the one who is making changes, another member of your team is making changes to the same branch. This is possible. So, the below step would help you for the same.

First, the member of your team (say B) would pull your remote branch(`branch-b`) to local.

```
git checkout -b onhold origin/branch-b
```

Now after `git status` it will show as

```
On branch onhold
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/branch-b'.
```

The team member B will change Branch upstream to origin/master as your branch-b was tracking to `origin/master` in the first place.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

It will show us `Branch 'onhold' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.`

Now B will do some changes and will push to the same remote branch forcefully by the below command.

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

and

```
git push origin onhold:branch-b -f
```

Now the PR will show us that team member B has removed one commit and added one commit. This PR is ready to merge with the origin/master once the PR gets approved.

I hope this might be helpful.